# C# reading console StandardOutput

Tags: c#, winforms, process, command-line-interface, redirectstandardoutput

I'm trying to run console commands from a C# winform application and read their output, but when I do the output contains Windows "copyright".

I don't think I can just split the output on each `\n` character and get rid of the starting lines, since not all cmd versions seem to output that garbage data, so is there a way to only get the "response" to the command and not the whole text present in the console as an output?

Here's my code:

```
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.Start();

    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("home-server scan");
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    cmd.WaitForExit();
    String output = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    String[] devices = output.Split('\n');
    textBox1.Text = output;
```

And here's my output as is (don't mind the console color codes):

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\users\corrado\Documents\Programming\Projects\home-server-gui\home-server-gui\home-server-gui\bin\Debug>home-server scan
[32mFound following devices:[39m
[32mvodafone.station[39m: http://192.168.1.1:8080

C:\users\corrado\Documents\Programming\Projects\home-server-gui\home-server-gui\home-server-gui\bin\Debug>
```

How do I get rid of all that garbage text?

Comment: Why are you launching `cmd.exe`. Why not launch `home-server.exe` directly as the filename you start then pass in just `scan` as the arguments in `StartInfo`

Comment: Wonky program, it is not very compatible with Windows.  Those strange "[32m" strings you see are terminal control sequences.  It is trying to change the text color.  Since unix program are usually available in source, you probably want to start there instead of trying to make it behave with Process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are running cmd.exe from Process.
Just change it to call directly your home-server.exe instead.
This should work.